# Subtracting datetime from google admin console logs

Tags: google-sheets

Google admin exports the following Date Time stamps which are not recognized by sheets. How can I get sheets to recognize these as date format? So, I can complete subtraction on them like "Feb 3, 2020, 2:00:29 PM GMT" minus "Feb 2, 2020, 1:00:09 PM GMT"

Comment: Hello, can you please specify if you want this difference in days, minutes, etc?

Comment: Thank you for the question difference in years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds would be great. The question is essentially how to have sheets recognize the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

I'll use these datetimes as example **Feb 3, 2020, 2:00:29 PM GMT** and **Feb 2, 2020, 3:00:09 PM GMT**

At the moment there's no sheet function which handles timezone so here's my approach:

First separate the days like so:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1 ,1), "mmm d, ") & INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1 ,2)
```

As well as the hours:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(SPLIT(A5, ","), 1, 3), "GMT", "")
```

Then simply calculate the difference in hours:

Date difference in hours

[image: Date difference in hours]

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1 ,1), "mmm d, ") & INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1 ,2)) - 
 DATEVALUE(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ","),1 ,1), "mmm d, ") & INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ","),1 ,2))
```

**DATEVALUE** Converts a provided date string in a known format to a date value which is a number that we can treat.

**NOTE: DAYS function will treat leap years as well so you can use it instead of DATEVALUE difference**

Hour difference

[image: Hour difference]

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","), 1, 3), "GMT", "")) - 
 TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ","), 1, 3), "GMT", ""))
```

**TIMEVALUE** will return the fraction of a 24-hour day which can be negative, I won't use `=ABS` function because I want to add this value to the date difference, so in adding this negative value we'll make the real difference between 2 dates.

Once we have both values we simply add them in order to retrieve the difference in hours:

```
=( DATEVALUE(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1 ,1), "mmm d, ") & INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1 ,2)) - 
 DATEVALUE(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ","),1 ,1), "mmm d, ") & INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ","),1 ,2)) ) * 24
 +
 (TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","), 1, 3), "GMT", "")) - 
 TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ","), 1, 3), "GMT", "")) ) * 24
```

And we can retrieve different formats like hours or minutes keeping in mind that DATEVALUE and TIMEVALUE have to be multiplied by 24.

[image: Total difference]

### References

- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [TIMEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350)
- [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039)
- [DAYS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061296): not used in my approach but it's useful.